# A question involving dimensions of some subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^p$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $f : M \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and a compact $f$-invariant set $\Lambda \subset M$ which is a $\textit{hyperbolic set}$ for $f$, i.e. there exist $\lambda \in (0, 1), c > 0$ and a decomposition $T_x M = E^s_x \bigoplus E^u_x$ for each $x \in \Lambda$ such that

1. $d_x f(E^s_x) = E^s_{f(x)}, d_x f(E^u_x) = E^u_{f(x)}$
2. If $v \in E^s_x$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\|d_x f^n(v)\| \le c \lambda^n \|v\|$
3. If $v \in E^u_x$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\|d_x f^{-n}(v)\| \le c \lambda^n \|v\|$.

In a book I read ("Dynamical Systems" - L. Barreira, C. Valls, page 97) it is written:

> > Let $x_m \in \Lambda$ be a sequence and consider the spaces $E^s_{x_m}, E^u_{x_m} \subset \mathbb{R}^p$. Since the dimensions $dim E^s_{x_m}$ and $dim E^u_{x_m}$ can only take finitely many values, there exists a subsequence $y_m$ of $x_m$ such that the numbers $dim E^s_{y_m}$ and $dim E^u_{y_m}$ are independent of $m$.

I don't understand why there exists a subsequence $y_m$ of $x_m$ such that the numbers $dim E^s_{y_m}$ and $dim E^u_{y_m}$ are independent of $m$ and why $dim E^s_{x_m}$ and $dim E^u_{x_m}$ are not independent of $m$?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, I guess that nowhere in the definition the hyperbolic set is connected, therefore, since the functions $dim E^s_{x_m}$ and $dim E^u_{x_m}$ are only locally constant they may have different values on different connected components. On the other hand, since the set of possible values is finite but the $E^{s/u}_{x_m}$ are infinite at least one of the values should be taken infinite times (you have to make infinite choices inside the finite set ${1,\ldots,m}$). There is your subsequence..